# VBA: reading Excel range into an object array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, object

How do I read an Excel range into an object array?

To clarify, for this Excel range of 6 cells...

```
John    Roberts    56
Sam     Alito      52
```

and this class...

```
Class supremes      
Public firstName        
Public lastName     
Public age  
Dim supreme As New supremes
```

I'd like to read the Excel range into an array of `supreme` such that:

```
arr(1).firstName = "John"   
arr(2).age = 52
```

For a standard array, this is done with a single assignment...

```
arr = range("supremes")
```

Is there a similar command to populate the object array?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213798

Comment: I know how to assign a range to an array.  My question was how to assign to an object array, as defined by a class module.

Comment: Then it might help those trying to answer your question if you explain what it is that you're trying to accomplish. If you just want to assign an array to another array in VBA, your question doesn't really have anything to do with Excel.  Perhaps you could post some prototype code?

Comment: if you read the question carefully, you'll find that it says "range" to object array, not array to array.  But I'll post an example...

Comment: In VBA, objects variables are pointers, so it will be `SET rng = Range"B4:D6"`

Comment: @rjsoft, Look at the second example in the link provided by Robert Harvey in the first comment. That is what your questions says you are looking for. If you are looking for something different then you need to reword your question to reflect what you really want.

Comment: I've updated my original question.

Comment: @rjsoft: are you a java programmer ? forget compulsive depency on objects. think results and efficiency. Happy new year.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any special way to read data into an array object. You just need to roll your own code.

```
dim i as long
dim rData as range
dim vData as variant

set rData=selection

vData=rData

for i=1 to ubound(vdata)
  arr(i).FirstName=vdata(i,1)
  arr(i).LastName=vdata(i,2)
  arr(i).Age=vdata(i,3)
next i
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.  For a large range, this looping may be a performance issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you minimize how often you have your VBA "talk" to Excel, that will help performance, not make it ideal, but help. Also, I've found using byref speeds things up and here's some other tips that can help keep things relatively fast: http://www.shamrock-software.eu/vb.htm also, I think Dictionary is faster than Collection, you'll have to double check on that one, but that could help keep things fast. I'm sure you know some of these already, but something might be new to you.

Comment: @rjsoft Jon49's variant array code will be very fast - much quicker than a standard range loop (+1)

Comment: @Jon49 I'm familiar with all the techniques from your link.  Thanks again.